# XmlChoiceIdentifier and List issue when serializing to XML

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I used Xsd2Code to generate C# classes from an XSD schema.

In the schema I have the following excerpt :

```
<hcparty>
  <firstname>some value</firstname>
  <familyname>some other value</familyname>
</hcparty>
```

The tool produced the following class:

```
[Serializable]
public class hcpartyType
{

    private List<string> itemsField;

    private List<ItemsChoiceType> itemsElementNameField;

    /// <summary>
    /// hcpartyType class constructor
    /// </summary>
    public hcpartyType()
    {
        itemsElementNameField = new List<ItemsChoiceType>();
        itemsField = new List<string>();
    }

    //[XmlArrayItem(typeof(ItemChoiceType))]
    [XmlChoiceIdentifier("ItemsElementName")]
    public List<string> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return itemsField;
        }
        set
        {
            itemsField = value;
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore()]
    public List<ItemsChoiceType> ItemsElementName
    {
        get
        {
            return itemsElementNameField;
        }
        set
        {
            itemsElementNameField = value;
        }
    }      
}

public enum ItemsChoiceType
{

    /// <remarks/>
    familyname,

    /// <remarks/>
    firstname,

    /// <remarks/>
    name,
}
```

First I had to add [Serializable] class decoration because it was missing.

When serializing to XML I get this error :

```
Type of choice identifier 'ItemsElementName' is inconsistent with type of 'Items'. Please use array of System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[MyNamespace.ItemsChoiceType, ...]].
```

OK, so I added:

```
[XmlArrayItem(typeof(ItemChoiceType))]
```

in the code above where I commented it. I guess it is at right place. The error remains.

I read the link below, so am wondering whether the bug still applies and I have to change my List to Array.

Anyone with same design issue ?
[Blog post about somewhat my case](http://binarynightmares.blogspot.be/2012/12/xml-deserialization-list-of-base-object.html)

[XmlSerializer issue with XmlChoiceIdentifier](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/681487/xmlserializer-consider-that-an-element-adorned-with-xmlchoiceidentifier-could-be-an-ienumerable-or-an-icollection-but-code-generation-fail)

Comment: Can a single HCParty element contain multiple familynames? If you can only have one of each name element, you should be able to add them as individual properties of the class (rather than the List<string>) and skip the complexity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Xml Serializer expects the type for the XmlChoiceIdentifier member to be an Array. Lists are not supported.

Try the following:

```
[Serializable]
public class hcpartyType
{

    private List<string> itemsField;

    private List<ItemsChoiceType> itemsElementNameField;

    [XmlChoiceIdentifier("ItemsElementName")]
    public string[] Items
    {
        get
        {
            return itemsField;
        }
        set
        {
            itemsField = value;
        }
    }

    [XmlIgnore()]
    public ItemsChoiceType[] ItemsElementName
    {
        get
        {
            return itemsElementNameField;
        }
        set
        {
            itemsElementNameField = value;
        }
    }      
}

public enum ItemsChoiceType
{

    /// <remarks/>
    familyname,

    /// <remarks/>
    firstname,

    /// <remarks/>
    name,
}
```

Comment: Thanks for resurrecting and answering such an old question, I even didn't remind it, hahaha